# Find the coordiantes of a rectangle using vectors

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have two coordinates which are vertices of a rectangle. They form the diagonal of the rectangle.

Is it possible, using vectors, to calculate the other two coordinates? I have tried calculating using circles and trig but have failed to find the solution.

Attached is a diagram what I am trying to solve. Any hints or tips would be much appreciated and thank you all in advance.[image]

Answer (score 3):

No.  Knowing the two opposite points is not enough to define the rectangle.  You know the length of $CD$ matches the length of $AB$ and the midpoints of the two diagonals match, but you can rotate $CD$ around the midpoint and form many rectangles

Comment: @Kel196 One could also easily picture "flipping" this rectangle about the diagonal AB (like holding a card at opposing corners and turning it over), so the rectangle shown is certainly not unique.  From there, **Ross Millikan**'s answer shows there are really an infinite number of other possibilities...